# Keep div scrollable with visible shadow

Tags: css

This is the situation:

[image]

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.one {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.two {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.three {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the property `overflow-y: auto;` cuts off the shadow of the elements with class `three`.

What I would like to have is something like this, but with containing block scrollable:

[image]

Is there a different way other then shrinking the `three` elements?

Comment: Give some `padding` to the `.two` class. Like this: `padding: 50px;`

Answer (score 0):

why not an inset shadow

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.one {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.three {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px inset black;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">

    </div>
    <div class="three">

    </div>
    <div class="three">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```